# How can I remove the current card?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I displayed all the user data (it's an array with an object for user infos) in the Card component, but I wonder how I can delete the current Card when I click the button.
Thank you in advance!

```
{user && user.map(user => (
  <div>
     <Card email={user.email}/>
     <button>Remove</button>
  </div>
))}
```

Answer (score 0):

At event handler to button element:

```
<button onClick={()=>handleRemove(user.id)}>Remove</button>
```

and create function to delete selected item:

```
const handleRemove (id) => {
return user.filter((user)=> user.id !== id)
}
```